# ios subview not responding to touch events

Tags: ios, uiview

I am trying to create a basic card flip animation for one of my view controllers.  Here is the current setup:

I have the base ViewController, this view controller has an XIB with a subview called containerView (shown below).

[image]

This container view basically then holds the two states of the "card" thats flipping.  I have a UIView subclass to represent the cardFront and the cardBack.  In the ViewController, I have some code in viewDidLoad to get a reference to both views:

**ViewController.m**

```
cardFront= [[UICard alloc]initWithType:YES];
cardBack = [[UICard alloc]initWithType:NO];
containerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;   
[containerView addSubview:cardBack];
```

Then, I basically just add and remove the subviews to containerView, with a small animation.

Then, I have two XIB's, one for cardFront, one for cardBack, and UICard decides which view to inflate.  So UICard looks like this:

**UICard.m**

```
-(id)initWithType:(BOOL)front{
    self = [super init];
    self.isFront = front;

    if(isFront){
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CardFront" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    else{
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CardBack" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    [self addSubview:self.view];


    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;



    return self;
}
//..later on, when i want to flip the card
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
                          duration:0.5
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                        animations:^
                        {
                            [cardFront removeFromSuperview];
                            [containerView addSubview:cardBack];
                            cardFront.isShowing = NO;
                            cardBack.isShowing = YES;
                            isFlipping = NO;
                        }
                        completion:NULL];
```

Pretty straight forward.  The problem is, no clicks get registered in my UICard view (either front or back).  I have buttons, etc, that just dont recieve any user interaction.  To test, I've placed

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
```

and

```
-(UIView *) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
```

in UICard.m, Neither get called in the UICard class.  All that I can think is that somehow the containerView is stealing all of the touch events, but in iOS (I beleive) the lowest subview gets the clicks first.  Anyone got any ideas on what could be going on here??

Edit:
Here is a picture of the cardBack.xib.  I wired up the view(files owner) to UICard's view property

[image]

Comment: What is self.view in your UICard class?

Comment: Its wired up to both cardFront.xib and cardBack.xib, which are freeform views.  I read somewhere thats how you inflate a custom xib on the fly

Comment: Your card view won't receive taps if it lies outside of your container view's bounds. You might wan to do [containerView recursiveDescription] in the console and verify that the frames are what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try `self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` in your UICard class as `self` is the actual view that you really want to enable user interaction.

Comment: this didnt make any difference.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Were you able to get cardfront or cardback to display at all? It may have something to do with the frame. One quick way to test is instead of loading view from nib file, you can just create a generic UIView and set its view and your UICard view frame to be the max screensize. Also, you should do if (self) before do anything in your init constructor.

Comment: The card is definitely showing up.  Thats one of the weirdest parts about it, everything looks correct.  Just none of the buttons grab touch events.  Im going to try instead of adding containerView to the ViewController, I will add just cardBack, and see what happends.  That way I can narrow down if containerView is stealing the clicks

Comment: Update: so after adding JUST the cardBack to the viewconterollerview ([self.view addSubview:cardBack];), I am still having the same problem.  This leads me to beleive its probably an issue with how im inflating the custom xib.  I cant find info on how else to do it though

Comment: @Jameo have you tried my suggestion? Just add a generic UIView with max view width and height instead of your NIB file and to see if you will receive touch event? Also, use self = [super initWithFrame:] instead of init.

Comment: Was there any solution to this? I'm having a similar problem and self.userInteractionEnabled = YES isn't solving it.